# Electricity consumption of unscrewed light bulb

Tags: power-consumption

I've got 4 light bulbs connected to one switch but I don't need this much light in my room. Plus I'm a bit afraid for my electricity consumption. Would unscrewing 3 of the 4 light bulbs lower it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it will lower your consumption, the real question will be how many people will  it take to do it..? j/k

Comment: How many engineers will it take **

Comment: If this thread stays open I think we'll find out :)

Comment: One to have hysterics, one to call the electrician, and one to fix the Martinis.

Comment: One up the ladder, one to hold the ladder, and 64 to rotate the room.